# Can we have same name for cookie and session variable in a project - PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Can we give same name to our cookie and session variables in the same project? Suppose we have a username stored in a cookie as "user_name" then can we have the same variable used for storing a session?

Is following possible and is OK to do so?

```
setcookie("user_name", $user_name, time() + 3600);
```

and

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
```

Or will it create any problem further?

Comment: it will be ok as they are stored in different arrays.

Comment: (Could should probably not store the user name - or other potentially forgeable information - in a cookie.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that.

When you do:

```
setcookie("user_name", $user_name, time() + 3600);
```

A cookie is created and stored in the browser with the name `user_name`.

When you do:

`$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;`

A session is generated in the server which has a field called `user_name`. Now this session information is passed between the browser and server in the form of a cookie that only has the information pertaining to accessing the session as opposed to having all the session data in it.

Since this session is not named, it will use the name of the default `PHPSESSID`

Apart from the fact that cookies are involved in both operations they do not have anything else in common. The only time you need to be careful is if you name your session and an unrelated cookie with the same name. Values inside session are bound inside that scope and it does not matter - as in the example you gave.

Answer (score 1):

yes for sure session data will be stored in server and related session id cookie will be set at the client side where as you are storing user name as cookie but storing sensitive data as cookie is not encouraged

Answer (score 1):

It's ok, they don't affect each other.

use session in php will only create a `PHPSESSID` cookie.

But why you need to save same thing in both cookie and session? in that case, store in session is enough.

Comment: cookie is used for remember me feature on front end of site while session is used for back end.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem. You can use the same names for `$_POST/$_GET/$_COOKIE/$_SESSION` but of course when accessing values you need to use proper array. If data is saved in `$_SESSION['user']` you need to use `$_SESSION['user']` and not for example `$_COOKIE['user']` because it may contain completely different value.

I don't know why you want to store user cookie name but I hope it's not for authorization purposes. Users can of course change their cookie value and then they could be logged as another users.